# Flow seems not to respect include option?

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I've setup my React project with a folder for common components I want to import directly.

```
src/
---components/
   ---common/
      ---/TextInput
      ---/TabSelector
```

[Full folder structure from root](http://pastebin.com/VQpmL9XZ)

Each of these folders in `common` have a index.jsx (and other resources such as style etc) with and `export default <name>` statement.

So my webpack config has the following configuration:

```
resolve: {
  modulesDirectories: [
    'node_modules',
    myCommonComponentsPath
  ] 
}
```

which allows direct imports: `import TextInput from 'TextInput'`

Trying to add this to `.flowconfig` (according to [flow's documentiation](https://flowtype.org/docs/troubleshooting.html#required-module-not-found)) is not working though:

```
[include]
./node_modules/
<PROJECT_ROOT>/src/components/common
```

This works with webpacks resolver (components load and work) but flow gives the following error:

```
9: import TextInput from 'TextInput';
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^ TextInput. Required module not found
```

Any help would be appreciated.
How do I resolve this?

Comment: What's your folder structure starting from the project root folder ?

Comment: Updated with a link now.

Comment: Thanks. Did you try `import TextInput from 'TextInput/index'; ` ?

Comment: Yes, tried all combinations I could think of.

`import TextInput from 'TextInput/index.jsx`
`import TextInput from 'TextInput/index`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [`module.system.node.resolve_dirname`](https://flow.org/en/docs/config/options/#toc-module-system-node-resolve-dirname-string) setting, which is different from the `include` setting. Since you are telling Webpack a new place to find modules, you also need to tell Flow about that new place.

```
[options]
module.system.node.resolve_dirname=node_modules
module.system.node.resolve_dirname=src/components/common
```

The paths are relative to the location of your '.flowconfig' file.

Comment: Ah sounds reasonable, thank you! I'll see if I find the time in the coming week to verify it. :)